# Are variables considered defined while calculation of their initialization value?

Tags: c++, enums, variable-declaration, variable-initialization

This is my small program:

```
enum Type
{
    b = 1,
    c = 2
};

int main()
{
    Type b = b;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs 0. Can I conclude that the above definition consists of this sequential steps?

1. Declaration of `b` as variable of type `Type`
2. Definition of that variable and initialization with `0` default value
3. Evaluation of it's new value, which includes the variable itself (with value 0)
4. Assigning that new value to variable.

And, do variables get initialized with 0 always, even if they are explicitly initialized?

My second question is - if it uses the variable in it's initialization list in specified example, why then I don't get error about ambiguity? Is compiler trying to find `b` in the variable list first, and only then checks for declared enumeration?

Comment: Don't do that. You'll just confuse yourself and anyone who has to maintain that code, which includes you in the future.

Comment: Sure, you are right! I just tried to understand the logic of language in that example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step 1 is correct, but the rest is wrong. What happens is that the variable `b` is defined and immediately initialized to the value of the variable `b`. This leads to *undefined behavior* because `b` is not initialized before it's used in its own initialization.

If you want to initialize it to `Type::b` then you need to explicitly write that:

```
Type b = Type::b;
```

Comment: Got it. And why it uses uninitialized variable instead of Type::b by default?

Comment: @MisterNobody `b` is in scope as soon as the `=` is reached

Comment: Yes, but my question is different. Consider `Type b; b = b;` code, why in the assignment the variable is being used, instead of `Type::b`?

Comment: the name is looked up in the innermost scope,  only looks in outer scopes if not found

Answer (score 1):

Although the variable is considered defined during its own initialization, it is still illegal to evaluate it unit its initialization is complete. That is why `Type b = b` is *undefined behavior*.

The reason why the variable is even defined is so that you could do this:

```
struct X {
    int *p;
    int a;
};
X x = {&x.a, 123};
cout << *x.p << endl;
```

Using the variable being initialized for purposes other than its own evaluation is legal. In the example above, the initializer of `x` must be able to refer to `x` in order to compute the address of its `a` member. This is legal, because `a` itself is not evaluated ([demo](http://ideone.com/GssHzf)).